# maxima for a function with 3 variables and use the result to prove an inequality

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I have the function: $f(x,y,z)=log(x) + log(y) + 3log(z)$ where I need to find the maxima with the conditions: $x>0, y>0, z>0, \space x^2+y^2+z^2=5r^2$, where $r$ is given. I then need to use that to show that the inequality:
$$abc^3 \le 27\left(\frac{a+b+c}{5}\right)^5$$ for all positive numbers $a, b ,c$.

The thing I have already done is to take the partial derivative of the function for $x,y,z$ and got that: $\frac{1}{x} = 0$, $\frac{1}{y} = 0$ and $\frac{3}{z} = 0$, but this doesn't make sense to me, since doesn't this means that it doesn't have any maxima points? Also how can I use the result to prove the inequality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By AM-GM
$$27\left(\frac{a+b+c}{5}\right)^5=27\left(\frac{a+b+3\cdot\frac{c}{3}}{5}\right)^5\geq$$
$$\geq27\left(\frac{5\sqrt[5]{ab\left(\frac{c}{3}\right)^3}}{5}\right)^5=abc^3$$

Comment: Nice proof Michael!